# Installing spacy via conda issues

Tags: installation, python, anaconda

I have recently uninstalled Python 32bit and switched to the 64bit version so that I could make use of `spacy`; a natural language processing package. When I attempt to install the package via conda prompt I receive this message:

```
(base) C:\Users\akin>conda install spacy
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:


Package importlib_metadata conflicts for:
pytest -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.12']
pytest-arraydiff -> pytest -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.12']
anaconda==2019.03 -> path.py==11.5.0=py36_0 -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.5']
importlib_metadata
pluggy -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.12']
pytest-openfiles -> pytest[version='>=2.8.0'] -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.12']
anaconda==2019.03 -> importlib_metadata==0.8[build='py37_0|py36_0']
path.py -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.5']
pytest-remotedata -> pytest[version='>=3.1'] -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.12']
astropy -> pytest -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.12']
pytest-doctestplus -> pytest[version='>=2.8'] -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.12']
pytest-astropy -> pytest[version='>=3.1'] -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.12']
Package zipp conflicts for:
pytest -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.12'] -> zipp[version='>=0.5']
pluggy -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.12'] -> zipp[version='>=0.5']
importlib_metadata -> zipp[version='>=0.3.2|>=0.5']
path.py -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.5'] -> zipp[version='>=0.3.2|>=0.5']
pytest-remotedata -> pytest[version='>=3.1'] -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.12'] -> zipp[version='>=0.5']
pytest-arraydiff -> pytest -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.12'] -> zipp[version='>=0.5']
pytest-astropy -> pytest[version='>=3.1'] -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.12'] -> zipp[version='>=0.5']
pytest-openfiles -> pytest[version='>=2.8.0'] -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.12'] -> zipp[version='>=0.5']
anaconda==2019.03 -> zipp==0.3.3[build='py37_1|py36_1']
zipp
anaconda==2019.03 -> importlib_metadata==0.8=py36_0 -> zipp[version='>=0.3.2']
astropy -> pytest -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.12'] -> zipp[version='>=0.5']
pytest-doctestplus -> pytest[version='>=2.8'] -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.12'] -> zipp[version='>=0.5']
Package mkl-service conflicts for:
scipy -> mkl-service[version='>=2,<3.0a0']
statsmodels -> scipy[version='>=0.14'] -> mkl-service[version='>=2,<3.0a0']
patsy -> scipy -> mkl-service[version='>=2,<3.0a0']
seaborn -> scipy -> mkl-service[version='>=2,<3.0a0']
scikit-learn -> mkl-service[version='>=2,<3.0a0']
mkl-service
anaconda==2019.03 -> mkl-service==1.1.2[build='py36hb782905_5|py37hb782905_5']
nltk -> scikit-learn -> mkl-service[version='>=2,<3.0a0']
scikit-image -> scipy[version='>=0.17'] -> mkl-service[version='>=2,<3.0a0']
```

I am able to install spacy via pip but I can not import it into my spyder environment. Is there anyway to get around having to install it via conda for it to be importable into spyder?